# XSLT moving nodes in a document and create the destination if necessary

Tags: xslt

I'm in a situation where I need to downgrade xml-documents from one version to another using XSLT. Being an XSLT-beginner I ran into trouble with this where I need to move information from one place to another:

```
<a>
  <b>123</b>
  <c>456</c>
</a>
```

Should transform into

```
<a>
  <d>
    <e>
      <b>123</b>
      <c>456</c>
    </e>
  </d>
</a>
```

Both b and c can occur 0 or 1 times. If neither of them are present in the original document, the d-node should not be created in the result. So
`<a><f>789</f></a>`
should remain unaffected.

Another example:

```
<a>
  <b>123</b>
  <f>789</f>
  <c>456</c>
</a>
```

Should transform to

```
<a>
  <d>
    <e>
      <b>123</b>
      <c>456</c>
    </e>
  </d>
  <f>789</f>
</a>
```

I have only tried XSLT version 1.0 so far, but using a newer version would work as well.

Would really appreciate some tips on how to solve this.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: What should be the result of transforming `<a><b>123</b><f>789</f><c>456</c></a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will process correctly both your examples, but it's not clear if it is correct for *all* your possible cases.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="a[b or c]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <d>
            <e>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="b | c"/>
            </e>
        </d>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (b | c)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is in XSLT 3.0.

Comment: Thank you for your input. As @y-arazim suggests the example does not cover my entire case. If I use the provided XSLT-code on the example Heiko-Theißen asked about I get a (for me) unexpected behaviour, the f-node is also moved into the d/e-node. Is there a way to prevent that? I'll update the original post with this example.

Comment: I have edited my answer to handle your updated example, but I cannot be sure it covers all possible scenarios. Examples are fine as an addition to rules, they do not replace them.