# How can I group these ul elements into ul and li elements XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Anyone can help me with xsl? I don't know how to achieve this:

This is my sample input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export>
   <article>
      <h4>Kernpunkte des Discours sind:</h4>
      <ul>eine Erkenntnistheorie, die nur das als richtig akzeptiert, was durch die eigene schrittweise Analyse und logische Reflexion als plausibel verifiziert wird,</ul>
      <ul>eine Ethik, gemäß der das Individuum sich im Sinne bewährter gesellschaftlicher Konventionen pflichtbewusst und moralisch zu verhalten hat,</ul>
      <ul>eine Metaphysik, die zwar (durch logischen Beweis) die Existenz eines vollkommenen Schöpfer-Gottes annimmt, aber kirchenartigen Institutionen wenig Raum lässt,</ul>
      <ul>eine Physik, die die Natur als durch zwar gottgegebene, aber allgemein gültige Gesetze geregelt betrachtet und dem Menschen ihre rationale Erklärung und damit letztlich ihre Beherrschung zur Aufgabe macht.</ul>
   </article>
</export>
```

I need to group all <ul> elements into <ul><li>…</li></ul> elements so that it will become like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export>
   <article>
      <h4>Kernpunkte des Discours sind:</h4>
      <ul>
         <li>eine Erkenntnistheorie, die nur das als richtig akzeptiert, was durch die eigene schrittweise Analyse und logische Reflexion als plausibel verifiziert wird,</li>
         <li>eine Ethik, gemäß der das Individuum sich im Sinne bewährter gesellschaftlicher Konventionen pflichtbewusst und moralisch zu verhalten hat,</li>
         <li>eine Metaphysik, die zwar (durch logischen Beweis) die Existenz eines vollkommenen Schöpfer-Gottes annimmt, aber kirchenartigen Institutionen wenig Raum lässt,</li>
         <li>eine Physik, die die Natur als durch zwar gottgegebene, aber allgemein gültige Gesetze geregelt betrachtet und dem Menschen ihre rationale Erklärung und damit letztlich ihre Beherrschung zur Aufgabe macht.</li>
      </ul>
   </article>
</export>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <export>
      <article>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </article>
    </export>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul/text()">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it does not work as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export>
   <article>
      Kernpunkte des Discours sind:
      <ul>
         <li>eine Erkenntnistheorie, die nur das als richtig akzeptiert, was durch die eigene schrittweise Analyse und logische Reflexion als plausibel verifiziert wird,</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>eine Ethik, gemäß der das Individuum sich im Sinne bewährter gesellschaftlicher Konventionen pflichtbewusst und moralisch zu verhalten hat,</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>eine Metaphysik, die zwar (durch logischen Beweis) die Existenz eines vollkommenen Schöpfer-Gottes annimmt, aber kirchenartigen Institutionen wenig Raum lässt,</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>eine Physik, die die Natur als durch zwar gottgegebene, aber allgemein gültige Gesetze geregelt betrachtet und dem Menschen ihre rationale Erklärung und damit letztlich ihre Beherrschung zur Aufgabe macht.</li>
      </ul>
   </article>
</export>
```

Can someone who is very good with xsl help me with my request?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Noel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XSLT moving nodes in a document and create the destination if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75521285/xslt-moving-nodes-in-a-document-and-create-the-destination-if-necessary) It's not exactly the same, but sufficiently similar.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen if i would have child nodes, yes, but I just have parent nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()"> 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::ul">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </ul>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is in XSLT 3.0.

---

If `article` has only `h4` and `ul` child elements, then you can do only:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="h4"/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ul"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Damn you're a genius! Thanks for the help, this is my exact expected output!!!

Comment: @NoelBürgler Getting the exact expected output is not very difficult. Guessing what in the given example is representative and what is just an example is (as you can see from the addition to my answer).